# Scroll first/last ListBox item to center of scrollview

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, scrollviewer

Is there any way at all to ensure that if my user selects an item in my `ListBox`, that the item is ALWAYS scrolled to the center of my `ListBox`? Obviously I can use the `ScrollToVerticalOffset` but it the user selects the last item in my list, the ListBox doesnt allow the ScrollViewer to scroll it into the center because its the last item.

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add several fake/empty items in your ListBox but in this case you have to avoid selection of theses fake items...

Comment: Yep, this not good solution, but if you do it right - it will work. ANother option is to make your own ListBox control...